# Are unitary representations of groups diagonalisable?

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $G$ be a countable semigroup, and let $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. Let
$(T_g)_{g\in G}$ be a unitary representation of $G$ over $H$, i.e. for all $g\in G$,
$T_g : G \to G$ is a unitary operator, and $T_g$ is also an isommetry. In addition,
$(T_g)_{g\in G}$ is a $G$-action on $H$, meaning that $T_{g_1 g_2}=T_{g_1} \circ T_{g_2}$
for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$.

Is it true that the action is diagonalizable, i.e. is it true that there is an orthonormal set $\left\{f_1,\dots, f_k\right\}$ in $H$ such that for all $i\in \left\{1,\dots, \ell\right \}$, there is an eigenvalue $(\lambda^{(i)} _g)_{g\in G}$ such that for all $g\in G$
$T_g(f_i)=\lambda^{(i)} _g f_i$? If this is not the case, would it be true if we assumed that $G$ is a group and not just a semigroup?

Comment: Your condition implies that $T_g\circ T_h= T_h\circ T_g$ for all $g,h\in G$. Unless $G$ is abelian, this need not be true.

Comment: Thank you very much fro the answer. Can we relax the assumption of commutativity to the semigroup being amenable, namely is the result true for amenable (semi-)groups?

Answer (score 4):

Let $$U_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},\quad U_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $U_1$ and $U_2$ are unitary and not diagonalizable simultaneously.
Let $G$ be the group generated by $U_1$ and $U_2.$ Then $G$ is countable and not diagonalizable.